# Audio signal to square wave

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, homework

I have a project, which includes a stage where I need an audio signal to be converted into a square wave or PWM so that it can be used as an input for a MOSFET driver.
My first question is, would PWM or the square waveform be better for the MOSFET driver?
And the second one is the best way to do the conversion. I have already tried the route that is used in D-class amplifiers, so a comparator is fed a signal as well as a triangle/sawtooth wave. Unfortunately, I couldn't make this work and I don't know why, so if you think that it is the best way let me know and I'll give it another shot:)

Preferably, Id like to do the conversion through an opamp stage or an NE555 and no microcontroller (if possible), as all are a part of project assignment rules.
Thank you for any advice and have an awesome day!

Comment: Why don't you just use a class D amplifier chip (without the power stage). ? They are cheap and very good.

Comment: You're going to have to define what "better" and "best" mean in the context of your project. A design can be optimized along many dimensions, such as cost, size, power, efficiency, complexity, reliability -- but not all at once!

Comment: To "convert" audio to a squarewave, just amplify it and clip it, or run it through a comparator (likely more accurate.)

Comment: There are many ways to "convert audio to a square wave". You need to decide exactly how your output square wave should be related to the input audio before anyone could realistically help with turning that requirement into a circuit.

Answer (score 2):

A square wave by strict defniton is just square wave, or PWM with 50% duty.

So unless you want to play only 50% PWM which is a pure square wave tone, you should send the audio as PWM.